# Why do my readAsDataURL return the same exact string for 2 different pages of a pdf

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf

```js
export async function convertFromPdf(f: any) {
  const pdfjsLib = require("pdfjs-dist/webpack");

  const pdf = await pdfjsLib.getDocument(f).promise;
  const pdfPages = await toImageData(pdf);

  const pages = await Promise.all(
    pdfPages.map(async (x) => {
      if (!x) return null;

      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      canvas.width = x.width;
      canvas.height = x.height;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx?.putImageData(x, 0, 0);

      const blob = await new Promise<Blob | null>((resolve) => {
        canvas.toBlob((blob) => resolve(blob));
      });

      if (!blob) return null;

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

      return await new Promise<string>((resolve) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      });
    })
  );

  return pages.filter((x) => x !== null) as string[];
}

async function toImageData(pdf: any) {
  const pdfPages = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= pdf.numPages; i++) {
    const page = await pdf.getPage(i);
    const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = viewport.width;
    canvas.height = viewport.height;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    const renderContext = { canvasContext: ctx, viewport: viewport };

    await page.render(renderContext).promise;
    pdfPages.push(ctx?.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height));
  }
  return pdfPages;
}
```

So I'm using the function above to convert pdf to image files (png). But somehow in certain cases, `reader.readAsDataURL(blob)` returns the same exact string for 2 different pages of the pdf. This is definitely bad because I want to make use of the url differently later on the UI part of things, but this will confuse the UI when doing certain selection as both will get selected as they both have the same url. Why does this happen?

Comment: If two images are identical then they will have the same encoding and thus the same data URL. Most likely source of identical images would be if the pages are blank.

Comment: Data URLs are somewhat resource-heavy. Consider using [object URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), perhaps indexed by page number (which is certainly unique for each page).

Comment: Probably not related to the issue at hand, but why do you create yet another canvas to get the image's data as a Blob when you could have gotten it through the first one in `toImageData`? That will use three times the memory necessary, for nothing.

Comment: @motto The two images are not identical, they have different information on them and they are not blanks.

Comment: @motto Could you expand more regarding your comment on object URLs